# How to sync selection from a "Attribute Slicer" to another page of same report

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

in the page 1 of my report, I have two slicers as below. One is Practice name slicer, the other is Project name. Selection of practice filters out the project name slicer. Based on the selection from the project name rest of the data is filtered.

[image]

I had to use a "Attribute Slicer" as the Project slicer, because there was a caching issue with default BI slicer (E.g: when you select A for Practice and then you select a1 for Practice, the selected option won't clear when you just change the Practice name to B. You have to select b1 from the Project list and close and open the slicer content to remove the previously selected value from the drop down)

Now my slicers are like this, one is default slicer and the other is Attribute slicer.

[image]

Now I need to sync the selection of Project to my next page also, and filter the data in the page 2. But, the Sync Slicer option is not available for the Attribute Slicer, although it is available and working perfectly fine for the default slicer.

I tried to apply a page level filter using a measure, which sets 1 for the Projects that match the selected value, but it is not allowing me to add the measure to Page level filter. Is there any way to achieve my goal. Appreciate if someone can help me.